# Disjoint set data structure in Julia

Tags: data-structures, julia

Trying to use the disjoint sets data structure as previewed [here](https://juliacollections.github.io/DataStructures.jl/stable/disjoint_sets/#Disjoint-Sets-1) I've simply typed

```
U = IntDisjointSets(10)
println(U)
```

and get the following error **ERROR: LoadError: UndefVarError: IntDisjointSet not defined**

Comment: Did you import the DataStructures library?

Comment: @DNF missed that part my bad. Works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DataStructures library must be loaded as stated by user DNF

You can load it by

`using DataStructures`

Before that though you must install it

```
using Pkg; Pkg.add("DataStructures")
```